# How to add a button to quick settings menu in android with react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to add a button to the menu shown in the picture below such that when the button is pressed it makes an HTTP request to some URL. The entire purpose of this app will be to create this button (I could've used macrodroid/tasker but I'd prefer a foss solution if it's not too much work). Is it possible to do this with react native?

[image]

Comment: There is not much that can be done on RN side, see https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/quicksettings-tiles.